# Deploy Saas and landingpage on same URL

Tags: netlify

I am gonna use Netlify to host my Saas.

I would like the landingpage to have the url for example `https://mysite.io` and my saas product to use `https://app.mysite.io`

I haven't tried this before, and netlify's documentation about Deploy Context doesn't work for me.

What I've tried so far

1. Created the landingpage on `master` branch and have `https://mysite.io` as primary domain on netlify.
2. Created another branch called `app` - in here the saas is comitted.
3. When I visit `app.mysite.io` it is showing the exact same page as master branch, but the URL is accessible though.

What goes wrong?

Comment: You should try creating a subdomain for your domain from your DNS and point it to your saas app and point the default domain to your landing page app.

Comment: Should I create 2 difference repos and host both on netlify?

Comment: yes, it is better to manage if you keep it separate.